# M2Eclispe support for Maven Lifecycle Extension

Tags: m2eclipse

I'm using a maven plugin with a `AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant`.

When importing and syncing the poms m2e doesn't seem to call the extension.

Is there some way to tell m2e to pick up an run Maven extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found associated M2e bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=486737
Seems to be fixed but not merged